# elasticache redis - python - connection times out

Tags: python, redis, serverless-framework, amazon-elasticache

I have a rather simple test app:

```
import redis
import os
import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def test_redis(event, context):
    redis_endpoint = None
    if "REDIS" in os.environ:
        redis_endpoint = os.environ["REDIS"]
        log.debug("redis: " + redis_endpoint)
    else:
        log.debug("cannot read REDIS config environment variable")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500
        }

    redis_conn = None
    try:
        redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_endpoint, port=6379, db=0)
        redis_conn.set("foo", "boo")
        redis_conn.get("foo")
    except:
        log.debug("failed to connect to redis")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500
        }
    finally:
        del redis_conn
        return {
            'statusCode': 200
        }
```

which I have deployed as a HTTP endpoint with serverless

```
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#

service: XXX

plugins:
  - serverless-aws-documentation
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true



provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  region: eu-central-1
  runtime: python3.6
  environment:
    # our cache
    REDIS: xx-xx-redis-001.xxx.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com



functions:
  hello:
    handler: hello/hello_world.say_hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          # private: true # <--  Requires clients to add API keys values in the `x-api-key` header of their request
          # authorizer:   # <--  An AWS API Gateway custom authorizer function

  testRedis:
    handler: test_redis/test_redis.test_redis
    events:
      - http:
          path: test-redis
          method: get
```

When I trigger the endpoint via API Gateway, the lambda just times out after about 7 seconds.
The environmental variable is read properly, no error message displayed.
I suppose there's a problem connecting to the redis, but the tutorial are quite explicit - not sure what the problem could be.

[The problem might need the need to set up a NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751946/setting-up-a-nat-gateway-with-vpc-using-serverless-framework), not sure how to accomplish this task with serverless

Comment: Are you able to execute the Lambda from the AWS console and have it connect to the redis then?  Perhaps my answer here will assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741141/how-to-use-aws-elasticache-from-lambda-in-c-sharp

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, not really. I put this on the side but I am back on it. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have the same issue. Celery tasks are often timing out...

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue as well. For me, there were a few problems that had to be ironed out

- The lambda needs [VPC permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-ec.html#vpc-ec-create-iam-role).
- The ElastiCache security group needs an inbound rule from the Lambda security group that allows communication on the Redis port. I thought they could just be in the same security group.
- And the real kicker: I had turned on encryption in-transit. This meant that I needed to pass `redis.RedisClient(... ssl=True)`. The [redis-py](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) page mentions that `ssl_cert_reqs` needs to be set to `None` for use with ElastiCache, but that didn't seem to be true in my case. I did however need to pass `ssl=True`.

It makes sense that `ssl=True` needed to be set but the connection was just timing out so I went round and round trying to figure out what the problem with the permissions/VPC/SG setup was.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the lambda in the same VPC and security group as your elastic cluster